# Check if ID in set of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

How can I check if there is a record with a particular ID in a set?

1. Get all users that match a condition
   `@users = User.where(something: true)`
2. Check if a particular user is in this set `user_is_in_set = @users.include? 7`

Step 2 is where I can't figure out the correct syntax.

I cannot simply do `user_is_in_set = User.where(something: true, id: 7)` for a relatively complicated reason.

Comment: `User.where(something: true, id: 7)` will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` that contains exactly one element or no elements. In other words, the above line is asking for a collection of users such that `something` is `true` and `id` is `7`. If you explicitly want a Boolean value you can use, e.g., `User.where(something: true, id: 7).any?`

Comment: Also, if you prefer to use `include?` as in your example, you would need to pass it a `User` object not just its `id`. For example, `user = User.find(7)` followed by `user_is_in_set = @users.include? user` would set `user_is_in_set` to either `true` or `false`. Hope it helps.

Comment: You can use user_is_in_set = User.exists?(something: true, id: 7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Include`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) is a method of array class and if you want to use it then you can do something like this:

```
@users = User.where(something: true).pluck(:id) #this will return an array of ids for which something is true
=> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

@users.include? 7
=> true
```